# PHP Multidimensional array merge two trees inside an array How to?

Tags: php

I want to merge two trees, in a multidimensional to one tree in the md array in php:

$array[1] = Array

```
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
```

$array[2] = Array

```
            [0] => d
            [1] => e
            [2] => f
```

result:

$array[1] = Array

```
            [0] => ad
            [1] => be
            [2] => cf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php

foreach($array[1] as $key => $value)
{
  $array[1][$key] = $value.$array[2][$key];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use array function to solve this Problem Like this :

$array = array('a','b','c');
$array2 = array('d','e','f');
$c = array_combine($array, $array2);
foreach($c as $key=>$value){
   $data[] = $key.$value;
}
print_r($data);
```